# How to clear an Excel array from vba?

Tags: excel, vba

How to clear an **Excel array**  ( with unknown shape) from VBA ? 
Given that I know that the array commences from "A1" for example.
So I need to get the shape , select and clear.

Comment: Do you mean a **Range** of cells or an internal VBA array ??

Comment: Not internal VBA array, but Excel array ( the one that displays "you cannot change part of an array" when you try to delete one single cell instead of the whole array ). Does this make sens ?

Comment: It makes sense............. **see my answer**

Comment: ANd how would I know what is the shape of "MyRange" ? My problem is that I don't know how to select it in order to clear its contents

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a range of cells:

```
MyRange.Clear
```

or

```
MyRange.ClearContents
```

**EDIT#1**

To clear a range of cells requires **two** parts:

1. Set the Range
2. apply a Clear method

If you have a block of formulas starting in **A1** then your posted code will work in a fashion similar to:

```
Sub ClearCells()
    Dim RangeToClear As Range
    '
    'the first part
    '
    d1 = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    d2 = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set RangeToClear = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(d1, d2))
    '
    'the second part
    '
    RangeToClear.ClearContents
End Sub
```

will work............I meant the the second part requires only one statement.

Comment: Common I wouldnt have asked such a simple thing, I have an excel array formula with unknown shape !

Comment: It does not matter what the shape is!!  You can clear all the cells at the same time with one command!  **You don't have to loop over rows or columns!**

Comment: one command ? how would vba know what cells to delete from the excel sheet ? it is not very clear what **MyRange** is in your answer.

Comment: Ya my problem was the **the first part**, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Now I understand....if the cells are part of an **array formula block** then use **Range("A1").CurrentArray.ClearContents**

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to use :

```
d1 =Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column 
d2 =Range("A1").End(xlDown).row 
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRowData, LastColData)).ClearContents
```